# Implementation of the post filter page in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter blog posts using this model:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    is_podcast = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True , unique=True , null=True , blank=True)
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    likes_count = models.IntegerField(default=0 , help_text="amount of likes")
    vip_members_only = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And I am using this view to filter the posts:

```py
def Index_view(request , slug=None):
    posts = Post.objects.filter()
    kind = request.GET.get('type')
    order = request.GET.get('order')
    author = request.GET.get('author')
    search = request.GET.get('search')

    if slug:
        cat = get_object_or_404(Category , slug=slug)
        posts.filter(category = cat)

    if search != '' and search is not None:
        posts.filter(Q(title__icontains = search))

    if kind != '' and kind is not None:
        if kind == 'podcast':
            posts.filter(is_podcast=True)
        if kind == 'all':
            pass
        if kind == 'post':
            posts.filter(is_podcast=False)  

    con = {'posts' : posts}
    return render(request , 'Weblog/posts.html' , con)
```

Here is the `urls.py` too:

```py
path('posts/', Index_view),
re_path(r'^posts/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', Index_view),
```

When I use this URL (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/posts/some-slug/?search=test`), I receive all the posts and the filtering does not work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to "overwrite" the `posts` variable.

```py
def Index_view(request , slug=None):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    kind = request.GET.get('type')
    order = request.GET.get('order')
    author = request.GET.get('author')
    search = request.GET.get('search')

    if slug:
        cat = get_object_or_404(Category , slug=slug)
        posts = posts.filter(category = cat)

    if search != '' and search is not None:
        posts = posts.filter(Q(title__icontains = search))

    if kind != '' and kind is not None:
        if kind == 'podcast':
            posts = posts.filter(is_podcast=True)
        #if kind == 'all':  --> useless
        #    pass
        if kind == 'post':
            posts = posts.filter(is_podcast=False)  

    con = {'posts' : posts}
    return render(request , 'Weblog/posts.html' , con)
```